# change of variable for bound of integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

This is in reference to page 149 of the book *Quantum Physics of Atoms, Molecues, Solids, Nuclei and particles*

How does one go from

$2A^{2} \int_{x = 0}^{x = \frac{a}{2}}\left(\frac{\pi x}{a}\right)^{2}cos^{2}\frac{\pi x}{a}dx$

to

$2A^{2}\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)^{3} \int_{x = 0}^{x = \frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{\pi x}{a}\right) ^{2}cos^{2}\frac{\pi x}{a}d\left(\frac{\pi x}{a}\right)$

Comment: Plug in $t = \dfrac{\pi x}{a}$. To avoid confusion, they should have used a different variable the second time.

Comment: @MathLover : are you sure about the result? in particular about the coefficient $\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)^3$

Comment: @MathLover are you sure?

Comment: Just check once whether the starting is $2A^{2} \int_{x = 0}^{x = \frac{a}{2}}\left(x\right)^{2}cos^{2}\frac{\pi x}{a}dx$

Comment: In that case you get to $2A^{2}\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)^{3} \int_{x = 0}^{x = \frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{\pi x}{a}\right) ^{2}cos^{2}\frac{\pi x}{a}d\left(\frac{\pi x}{a}\right)$. So you are right, either there is a mistake in the first one or the second one. I had not checked all the working earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the result is correct. Skipping $2A^2$ that is not necessary to understand the passages, substituting $y=\frac{\pi x}{a}$ you get that the original integral

$$\int_{x=0}^{x=a/2}\left(\frac{\pi x}{a}\right)^2\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi x}{a}\right)dx$$

becomes

$$\frac{a}{\pi}\int_{y=0}^{y=\pi/2}y^2\cos^2y dy$$

---

instead, if the integral was

$$\int_{x=0}^{x=a/2}x^2\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi x}{a}\right)dx$$

the result would have been the one you posted